# why ranks were different?

Tags: sas

One:

```
data have;
input x1 x2;
diff=x1-x2;
a_diff= round(abs(diff), .01);
* a_diff=abs(diff);
cards;
50.7 60
3.3  3.3
28.8 30
46.2 43.2
1.2  2.2
25.5 27.5
2.9 4.9
5.4 5
3.8 3.2
1 4
;
run;

proc rank data =have out =have_r;
      where diff;
      var   a_diff      ;
      ranks a_diff_r;
run;

proc print data =have_r;run;
```

Results:

```
Obs     x1      x2     diff    a_diff    a_diff_r
 1     50.7    60.0    -9.3      9.3        9.0
 2     28.8    30.0    -1.2      1.2        4.0
 3     46.2    43.2     3.0      3.0        7.5
 4      1.2     2.2    -1.0      1.0        3.0
 5     25.5    27.5    -2.0      2.0        5.5
 6      2.9     4.9    -2.0      2.0        5.5
 7      5.4     5.0     0.4      0.4        1.0
 8      3.8     3.2     0.6      0.6        2.0
 9      1.0     4.0    -3.0      3.0        7.5
```

Two:

```
data have;
input x1 x2;
diff=x1-x2;
a_diff=abs(diff);
cards;
50.7 60
3.3  3.3
28.8 30
46.2 43.2
1.2  2.2
25.5 27.5
2.9 4.9
5.4 5
3.8 3.2
1 4
;
run;

proc rank data =have out =have_r;
      where diff;
      var   a_diff      ;
      ranks a_diff_r;
run;

proc print data =have_r;run;
```

results:

```
Obs     x1      x2     diff    a_diff    a_diff_r
 1     50.7    60.0    -9.3      9.3        9.0
 2     28.8    30.0    -1.2      1.2        4.0
 3     46.2    43.2     3.0      3.0        7.5
 4      1.2     2.2    -1.0      1.0        3.0
 5     25.5    27.5    -2.0      2.0        5.0
 6      2.9     4.9    -2.0      2.0        6.0
 7      5.4     5.0     0.4      0.4        1.0
 8      3.8     3.2     0.6      0.6        2.0
 9      1.0     4.0    -3.0      3.0        7.5
```

Attention Please,Obs 3,9,5,6, why ranks were different? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the code below and you'll see that they are actually different.  That's because of inaccuracies in numeric storage; similar to how 1/3 is not representable in decimal notation (0.333333333333333 etc.) and 1-(1/3)-(1/3)-(1/3) is not equal to zero if you use, say, ten digits to store each result as you go (it is equal to 0.000000001, then), any computer system will have some issues with certain numbers that while in decimal (base 10) appear to store nicely, in binary do not.

The solution here is basically to round as you are, or to `fuzz` the result which amounts to the same thing (it ignores differences less than 1x10^-12).

```
data have;
input x1 x2;
diff=x1-x2;
a_diff=abs(diff);
put a_diff= hex16.;
cards;
50.7 60
3.3  3.3
28.8 30
46.2 43.2
1.2  2.2
25.5 27.5
2.9 4.9
5.4 5
3.8 3.2
1 4
;
run;
```

Comment: 46.2-43.2=3.0    1.0-4.0=-3.0 abs is 3.0 rank is 7.5,7.5 but 25.5-27.5=-2.0   2.9-4.9=-2.0 abs is 2.0 rank is 5,6,why?

Comment: Read my answer and run the code that I included.  Your `put` statements use the default format (`BEST12.`) which is not big enough to show the difference in the two rows.  There oughtn't be a difference, of course, but there is; hence, the round solution is correct.

Comment: the  difference(3.0 and -3.0) hex16. were the same(4008000000000000), but the  difference(2.0 and 2.0) hex16. were not the same(4000000000000000,4000000000000001),why? can you explain?